# Installing new outlet in the middle of an existing run

Tags: electrical, basement, junction-box

We're in the process of doing some minor reno in our basement, and we'd like to put our entertainment center in one corner.  Unfortunately there's no plug near there, so I want to add one.

The basement is poured concrete with old faux-wood paneling over 1x3 strips. The romex for the existing plugs generally runs along the sill plate, stapled to the rafters.  Because of the space constraints in the wall, I'd rather not try to pigtail in the box, so the solution I was thinking was to cut out the existing line near where I want the new outlet, install a junction box in the ceiling to some new romex, and the back out of the outlet into a second junction box, which connects to the rest of the run.

Am I out of my mind, or does this work? Is there a better way?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/102488/extending-an-outlet-in-the-middle-of-a-run?rq=1

Comment: You only need one junction box if you can get a few inches of slack out your existing run.  Your new junction box must remain accessible.  You can T off from that existing line, you don't need to Daisy chain outlet to outlet.  Make sure your cutting into an always hot circuit and not something switched.

Comment: @Tyson - A few inches of slack really need to be about 10 inches to permit a Tee connection off an existing run. It has been my experience that this can be very uncommon to achieve when the run was installed in what was probably a point to point path. So based upon that I think the OP is probably right about the need for a couple of junction boxes that allow the insertion of a new length of wiring between them.